# Get the text from an element by clicking in angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm new in Angular2, and I'm used to use Jquery, but I can't use Jquery in Angular 2. I want to get the text of an element that I'm clicking (like using the function $(this).text()in Jquery) in angular 2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<div #myElement (click)="doSomething(myElement.innerText)">someText</div>
```

or

```
<div (click)="doSomething($event.target.innerText)">someText</div>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  doSomething(text) {
    console.log(text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but why you use `innerText` instead of `textContent`? el.innerText vs el.textContent vs $(el).text() https://plnkr.co/edit/07qZlaqck3uJmHUQmRWS?p=preview

Comment: I don't know jQuery and `innerText` seemed to be close enough for such a vague description "get the text of an element" ;-) Thanks for your Plunker!